# rails4にて、rails_apiとwebベースのhtmlアプリを同時に使う

Tags: ruby-on-rails

JSON APIとHTMLベースのwebアプリ両方を含んだrails4アプリを作ろうとしています。
`/api`以下に来たリクエストに関してはパフォーマンスの最適化ためrails_apiで使用される最低限のミドルウェアを介してレスポンスを返し、それ以外のリクエストに関してはデフォルトのRailsのミドルウェアセットを介して処理をさせていと考えています。

現状、
- rails_api gemを追加
- routes.rbにてapiをnamespaceで分ける
- apiのコントローラに関しては`ActionController::API`を継承させる
- HTMLベースのコントローラに関しては`ActionController::Base` を継承させる

という方針で進めています。以下、主な部分のコードです。

app/controllers/base_api_controller.rb

```
class BaseApiController < ActionController::API
    ...
end
```

app/controllers/api/projects_controller.rb

```
module Api
  class ProjectsController < BaseApiController
    def index
      ..
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ..
end
```

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ..
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
  resource :projects
end

resource :projects
```

config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/controllers/api
)
```

この状態で`/api/projects`にリクエストをなげるとうまく`/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb`が処理してくれるのですが, `/projects`にアクセスすると`/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb`に処理して欲しいところ、以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
Unable to autoload constant ProjectsController, 
expected /app/controllers/api/projects_controller.rb to define it.
```

どのようにすれば正しく動くように修正できますでしょうか。
もしくは、そもそもこの実装方針自体おかしいようでしたら代案を教えていただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の設定が必要なさそうです。

```ruby
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/controllers/api
)
```

`ProjectsController`をロードする際`autoload_paths`に設定されているディレクトリ以下からprojects_controller.rbを探そうとします。
`autoload_paths`にapp/controllers/apiが入っていると、app/controllers/projects_controller.rbより先にapp/controllers/api/projects_controller.rbが見つかってしまいます。
Railsは`ProjectsController`が定義されることを期待しているのでエラーになってします。

Railsはネームスペースの下のクラスを、ネームスペースと同じ名前のディレクトリの下から探すので、`autoload_paths`からapp/controllers/apiを削除しても、`Api::ProjectsController`はうまく動きます。

Railsガイドの[定数の自動読み込みと再読み込み](http://railsguides.jp/constant_autoloading_and_reloading.html)でこのあたりの仕組みが詳しく解説されているので、参考になると思います。

Comment: なるほど！どうもありがとうございます！